# Can Git be used to update software on client machines?

Tags: git, patch, auto-update

So I had an idea, and I need a second opinion because I'm worried I might be off my rocker. Could local software (i.e. a videogame or word processor) be updated on the client side using 
Git? For example, everytime the client launcher opens up it runs a `git pull`. Then pulls from a master repository containing a complete client install.

**Is this a good idea?  What could go wrong?  Is this looked down upon?**

Libraries already exist like [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/) that allow git to be integrated into an application, so why not use this for software patches?

Comment: this seems more like an opinion question than a concrete programming question...

Comment: I can see this working OK for apps consisting of many individual files. But very poorly for monolithic apps consisting of few compiled files. I'd also worry because the whole thing can easily be hosed by removing some .git metadata with virtually no recourse for the user. Also consider that the .git meta data can be quite substantial, usually at least doubling the folder size.

Comment: This isn't a good idea for compiled objects like binaries, because Git is not designed to store those efficiently. So that just leaves you with plain text source code, but then you'd have to compile those into binaries on the client machine, and that isn't so great either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in fact some software already does this. For example, I'm using `zsh` with the `oh-my-zsh` extension which asks me to do an update every so often when a new terminal is launched (and a git pull is initiated when the user accepts).

This method would work best for interpreted languages (as opposed to compiled languages), since it's much more efficient for git to work with text, however binary files would work.

Note that `git` is "abused" for other things as well - for example the popular homebrew OS X package manager uses git to update its database of available packages.

Answer (score 1):

**Is this a good idea?**

This is a subjective question, so I don't have an answer for you.  But it's certainly an *interesting* idea.  Check this out, from [the Git documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals):

> First, if it isn’t yet clear, Git is *fundamentally* **a content-addressable filesystem** with a VCS user interface written on top of it. *(emphasis added)*

Git is described in terms of the *plumbing* and the *porcelain*.  The *plumbing* is the back-end, which is really just a filesystem.  The *porcelain* is what you are used to when you interact with Git, and it is very much geared toward source control.

**What could go wrong?**

If you're using it to distribute binary packages, make sure you [check this link out](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Binary-Files).  Git can mistakenly think binary files are *not* binary.

There is also a lot of folksy wisdom about Git not handling binary files well.  I can't find any source material to back that up, but my own experience is that it deals with them just fine.  Obviously, you can't *merge* binary files, but I doubt you would do that anyway for what you described.

Lots of other things could go wrong, since Git will allow you to shoot yourself in the foot quite happily, but that is (IMO) one of it's greatest strengths.

**Is this looked down upon?**

For every good idea, you will find plenty of haters.  For every bad idea, you'll find plenty of fools.

Comment: I forgot to mention - under "what could go wrong" - don't forget that the client will not only be storing the current version, but *all previous versions*, too, since it clones an entire copy of the repository and it's history.  So you'll be using a lot of disk space.

Comment: Wondering if this couldn't be used as an advantage. For instance say some class calls a method and the method is not defined in the new version of the file, looking for older files such that the classes still match... This could resolve some compatibility issues.